# Parenthesis on .upper() and .apply(str.upper)

Tags: python, pandas

Why do `upper` in `df.apply(df.str.upper)` doesn't require a parenthesis, but `upper()` method requires them as in `df.str.upper()`?

Is there some concept I've miss?

Comment: you should and pandas tag, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `()` means "call this function now".

```
print(str.upper())
```

Referring to a function without the `()` does not call the function immediately.

```
map(str.upper)
```

The `str.upper` function is passed to the `map` function. The `map` function can now decide what it does with the `str.upper` function. It might call it once, or multiple times, or store it somewhere for later use.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.apply(function_name)`, the internals treats function_name as a reference to the function that has been applied. Hence, only the function name is passed and that too without parentheses.
When it is applied to the entity, it will be accessed from the `function_name`.
Its just like passing a function as an argument to another function.

Example:

```
def fun(x):
   return x*x

def fun_b(function):
   return function(3)

print(fun_b(fun))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python everything is an object. A function without parentheses is not evaluated and is treated as an object. A function with parentheses is immediately evaluated.

For example:

```py
>>> def return_one():
...     return 1
... 
>>> return_one  # return the object reference, do not evaluate
<function return_one at 0x7fb76d3f4bf8>
>>> return_one()  # evaluate the function
1
```

With this in mind, the `.apply` method takes a **function object** and then calls it at a later point in time. If you were to write `.apply(str.upper())`, `str.upper()` would evaluate to a `str` instead of a `func` object.